# Netbeans: how do I format/pretty up code with no EOLs?

Tags: netbeans, format

I'm looking at wordpress plugin files and came across a javascript file that has no EOLs (line breaks)--it's one long line. It's NOT a Unix/Windows EOL thing--I verified lack of EOLs with a hex editor. Selecting this line and telling Netbeans to format did nothing.  Figuring lack of EOLs after semicolons might be asking too much of the IDE, I then did a search and replace to add EOLs after each semicolon.  Now I have braces (blocks) with no EOLs.  I went into javascript format settings for the braces and changed all "Preserve Existing" to newline. I then selected all code and told it to format.  It did some indenting but didn't add one newline after a brace.

I'm using Netbeans 11.0 (Windows).

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

If you're interested in reproducing this, get the wp photo album plus plugin.  It's the wppa.min.js file in the js folder.

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: I'm REALLY starting to think this is a bug.  I tried to do a replace all on the braces and it couldn't find any (there are LOTS of them).  Hex editor shows there are no unusual characters surrounding the braces.

Comment: Interesting.  I just learned about "minify".  While this isn't the app that stripped the EOLs (because the file has descriptive variable names), it's very close to what I see.  I found an online source that did a decent job of undoing the mess:  [unminify](http://www.unminifyjs.com/).